# Google Cloud DNS Console or UI

Tags: google-cloud-dns

Does anybody know if we can maintain the DNS entries using google cloud console or any other UI? I couldn't find any place in cloud console for DNS admin.

Does the REST API only way to maintain the zone and DNS entries?

Answer (score 4):

Update: There is now a UI for Cloud DNS in the Networking tab of the Developers Console.

Click here to check it out: https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/dns/zones

Answer (score 1):

We have written one in Rails:
https://github.com/mainio/gcdns

It's not perfect (and might be buggy) but we're using it ourselves.

Comment: After I created my project and upload p12 file from my service account, I am getting 
Authorization failed. Server message: { "error" : "invalid_grant" }

Comment: Please see the github issue thread on this matter that you just created: https://github.com/mainio/gcdns/issues/1. Seems to be a misconfiguration in your project credentials.

Comment: Hi guys -- I just updated my answer above. The Developers Console now has a UI for Cloud DNS.